How quanitization levels in ADC are adjusted?
I understand Quantization in an Analog-to-Digital Converter (ADC)
refers to the process of converting the continuous analog signal
into discrete digital values.
For example: To change the radio station, I can simply turn the
tuning knob.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your typical AM/FM radio receiver doesn't even have an ADC, so it's especially confusing what your example is meant to illustrate.

@user1850479  what he means is that what sort of "knob" changes the LSB in an ADC.

"Quantization levels" (LSB voltage step size) normally is not adjusted at runtime, but is set at design time by choosing the device that drives the constant reference voltage level. The reference voltage is divided among the (2^N)-1 steps, not considering various non-idealities.

@MarkU, if you adjusted the reference voltage (on an ADC with an external reference), that would also change the lsb.

Each B-bit ADC receives a voltage reference, \$V_{REF}\$, and uses a specific method to compare the signal to \$ 2^B\$ equally-spaced fractions of this voltage. Depending on the type of ADC, this method of comparison changes significantly. I will breakdown the performance of three of the most popular choices for you as an example. A google search will reveal a vast body of literature for each structure. To adjust the quantization levels or the least-significant bits (LSBs), you simply change \$ V_{REF}\$. This choice will alter your SNR and mismatch tolerance and must be made mindfully.
1. Flash ADC: constructs all of the \$ 2^B\$ levels using a voltage divider, and compares the input signal to all of these levels in parallel. Pros: Speed, Cons: Hardware, Mismatches, Loading the Input, Power Consumption.
2. SAR ADC: uses B clock cycles and resolves a bit per clock cycle. In each cycle, compares the input to the bisected value of the reference. For example, if you have 3 bits, you compare to \$V_{REF} / 2\$ in the first clock cycle, then if the signal is above that, you compare to \$3V_{REF} / 4\$, and so on. Pros: Power Efficient, Less Hardware Cons: Lower Speed, Complicated Control Logic.
3. Pipelined ADC: very similar to SAR, but pipelines the operation. After the initial B clock cycles, it resolves B bits per clock cycle. This time, usually the signal is compared to \$V_{REF} / 2\$ and the residue of the comparison is doubled and passed on to the next stage. Pros: Speed, Less Loading on the Input Cons: Hardware, Power Consumption.
There are many other ADC architectures, and the method of achieving the quantization in each may vary significantly. Some of the most interesting emerging architectures do the comparison in the time domain. They use voltage-to-time conversion (VTC) and time-to-digital conversion (TDC) to achieve the quantization, eliminating some of the challenges of the traditional voltage-domain architectures.
